# Unresolved module with id: dojo/io/script, Unresolved module with id: dijit/form/Form

Tags: dojo, ibm-connections

I have created a widget to load as an application for IBM Connection, while adding the application getting following error.

Unresolved module with id: dojo/io/script
Unresolved module with id: dijit/form/Form

Code snippet:

```
define("lconn/core/filepublish", [
    'dojo/ready','dojox/xml/parser', 
    'dijit/form/Form', 'dojo/io/script', 'dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore', 
], function(ready,parser, Form, script, ItemFileReadStore) { 
    dojo.declare("lconn.core.filepublish", null,{

            UrlPrefix:null,
            timeoutDuration: null,
            onLoad: function()
            {       
                console.log("UrlPrefix="+UrlPrefix);
                var valArgs = {
                    url :kosmosUrlPrefix+ "/XXX/XXX/XXXX/admin/ValidateCommunity?communityUuId="+communityUuid,
                    callbackParamName:"validatecallback",
                    timeout:timeoutDuration,
                    load: function(response, ioArgs){       
                        console.log('in load function to validate if its comunity....');
                    }
                }
            }       
    });
});
```

Comment: You got an error for all of the required resource or just for these 2? Is it running within a built dojo ? If this is the case, maybe the dojo loaded in the page is a custom base build and does not provide the 2 packages you need

Comment: Only for these 2.. Loading this widget as an application to IBM Connection

Comment: which version 4? not 5?  I know in 5 this breaks.